# How jquery get dynamic element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jsp element id that is dynamically setup.
It looks like 
       `id=<%= config.getName()%>`
How can I get the id of those when I click them?

How to pass the element id to the function like:

```
$('****').click(function(){

}
```

Comment: You want to bind `click` event to that element right?

Comment: what is your purpose to get that specific id? is your element an array?

Comment: Usually you can get very good suggestions if you share with us what your goal is. For example if you're trying use the `id` attribute to carry data, `data` attributes may be better for doing that. So feel free to let us know what you want to achieve if you're open to suggestions.

Comment: The design of the page is based on xml configuration, so the page will be dynamical page based on which element the user asked. For one user, the page may have two dropdown lists. And for another user, the page will have more dropdown and other fields like Data entry and Text Box. In this way, all elements in the page will not have a fixed name, that means the id can only setup like id=<%=user.configue()..%>. I need to pass the id to jquery functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".common").click(function()
{
alert(this.className);
alert(this.id);
//  here u can get class name id  value and pass to any function u want 
// functinname(this.className);
});

});
</script>


<div id="vik" class="common">vik div</div>
<div id="cha" class="common">cha div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the class setup fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add c class name on your button.

```
<input type='button' class='myButtonClass' id=<%= config.getName()%> />
```

You can now use the class as selector.. You have, i guess 3 ways to get the id attribute.

```
$('.myButtonClass').click(function(){
    // first option
    console.log(this.id); // use this only, not $(this), .id will not work on jquery object
   // second option
   console.log($(this).prop('id'));
   // third option 
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that solves my problem. I setup the class for the same elements like two input field with different ids. And the correct id can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use class to get dynamic id as:

```
$(".any").click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I tried .any but cannot trigger the alert to get the id information.

Comment: did you assign class to triggered element...?

Comment: Thank you, Dinesh, the class setup is working. But I would like to use .classname to replace the .any since I will use different function for different elements.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there another unique attribute? for example, class name, tag name,...

if nothing, there is another way that create unique attribute value in the tag.

```
<div id=<%=config.getName()%> dynamicId="true"></div>
```